# "0 new answer to this question"

Tags: bug, notifications

There seems to be a bug in the new answer notification system that rarely manifests (this is the first time I've seen it). It seems to occur when two answers are posted almost simultaneously. I saw a notification that there was a new answer and clicked on it; this caused not one but two answers to appear, and a second or so later a notification appeared saying "0 new answer to this question". This happened at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176852), and according to the timestamps the two answers were posted within $7$ seconds of each other. Here's a screenshot of the spurious notification (view in new tab or window to get the full resolution):

[image: 0 new answer to this question]

Comment: At the moment that this happened, were you typing an answer yourself?

Comment: @balpha: I think I was, but I'm not entirely sure -- I did start writing an answer to that question some time shortly before this happened, but I'm not sure whether I was working on it at that moment.

Comment: @balpha: The same thing just happened again under very similar circumstances at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292024; the two answers there were posted within $6$ seconds of each other according to the time stamps, and I was working on an answer myself when it happened.